# C:Having some troubles with a pointer to uint8_t[]

Tags: c, pointers, microcontroller, coap

I'm working with microcontrollers and got following working code:

.h file

```
const static  uint8_t state0[] = "Off";
const static  uint8_t state1[] = "ROMLoad";
const static  uint8_t state2[] = "RAMLoad";
const static  uint8_t state3[] = "PacketSend";
const static  uint8_t state4[] = "Process";
```

.c file

```
        switch (coapapp_vars.state) {
        case 0:
            packetfunctions_reserveHeaderSize(msg, sizeof(state0) - 1);
            memcpy(&msg->payload[0], &state0, sizeof(state0) - 1);
            break;
        case 1:
            packetfunctions_reserveHeaderSize(msg, sizeof(state1) - 1);
            memcpy(&msg->payload[0], &state1, sizeof(state1) - 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            packetfunctions_reserveHeaderSize(msg, sizeof(state2) - 1);
            memcpy(&msg->payload[0], &state2, sizeof(state2) - 1);
            break;
        case 3:
           packetfunctions_reserveHeaderSize(msg, sizeof(state3) - 1);
           memcpy(&msg->payload[0], &state3, sizeof(state3) - 1);
           break;
        case 4:
            packetfunctions_reserveHeaderSize(msg, sizeof(state4) - 1);
            memcpy(&msg->payload[0], &state4, sizeof(state4) - 1);
            break;
        }
```

I do want to change this code to shorten the file (to have less code uploaded) by calling memcpy after the switch. Therefor I need to use a pointer that points to the correct value from .h by using the cases to fill in the pointer.
Unfortunately, I have not been able to get it to work. So I'm pretty clueless where I need to use the * or &, or not at all, to get it work. I've tried out a lot of different ways but none succeeded.

The questions then are: What type of uint8_t (uint8_t/uint8_t*/uint8_t**) do I use to initialize the variable pointing to one of the char arrays?
How do I fill in that (pointer) variable (ptr = state/ptr = &state/ptr=&state[0]/...)? 
How do I need to use the (pointer) variable in the memcpy function(ptr/&ptr/*ptr/&(*ptr)/...)?

I am aware that I will need to use a variable that I set myself for the size.

More information if needed: This code is used in OpenWSN. I'm working with a IoT device/microcontroller. I'm using their COAP implementation to send information to a browser.

Edit: Both the reserveHeaderSize function and memcpy function will be placed after the switch. 
As pointed out by the correct answer, this is pretty simple but I kept overlooking a small stupid error on my part: I wasn't remove the sizeof in the third argument so I was basically doing sizeof(size). Derp

Comment: Note, BTW, that `const static` is obsolescent. C wants to you to use `static const` instead. Also, it is not immediately clear why you insist on having multiple copies of the original literals (a separate set in each translation unit) instead of working with the original literals directly. Just to be able to use `sizeof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you want to assign a pointer variable in each `case` so that you can call `memcpy()` afterwards. If it's so it's simple. You only need to set the size to be copied in each case too, but you have already mentioned it.

That's how it goes:

```
    uint8_t *stateptr;    // pointers can be assigned to arrays
    size_t  size;

    switch (coapapp_vars.state) {
    case 0:
        packetfunctions_reserveHeaderSize(msg, sizeof(state0) - 1);
        stateptr = state0;
        size = sizeof state0;
        break;
    case 1:
        packetfunctions_reserveHeaderSize(msg, sizeof(state1) - 1);
        stateptr = state1;
        size = sizeof state1;
        break;
    // other cases
    }
    memcpy(&msg->payload[0], stateptr, size-1);
```

Please note that in your code you also could have written

```
  memcpy( &msg->payload[0], state0, sizeof state0 - 1 );
```

instead of `..., &state0, ...`.

Comment: It is indeed that simple... I had tried this before but I didn't work because of one stupid mistake I kept overlooking... I had left sizeof() in memcpy and had only replaced the state variable with the size variable, basically writing sizeof(size) which is obviously wrong. 
This questions is actually obsolete now but I would like to thank you a lot! Without reading your code I would of kept overlooking that small error. So once again, much thanks!

It's always the small stupid things that messes up, hiding in plain obvious sight while we look for something complex to be wrong

Comment: I know that for sure :-) Glad I could help